# Strange error inserting rows followed by a rollback in oracle11g

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, rollback

Writing a script to test a (to be written) trigger, but I am getting a strange error message if I rollback the change.
Here is the test script

```
    insert into prescription values(
  143, 115, 
  to_date('January 15, 1989, 11:00 A.M.',
  'Month dd, YYYY, HH:MI A.M.',
  'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American'),
  5, 12, 'hours', 12);
select * from prescription;
rollback;
```

After scrolling about half way through the rows returned by the select statement the table evaporates and I get hit by an error message:

```
ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence
01002. 00000 -  "fetch out of sequence"
*Cause:    This error means that a fetch has been attempted from a cursor
           which is no longer valid.  Note that a PL/SQL cursor loop
           implicitly does fetches, and thus may also cause this error.
           There are a number of possible causes for this error, including:
           1) Fetching from a cursor after the last row has been retrieved
           and the ORA-1403 error returned.
           2) If the cursor has been opened with the FOR UPDATE clause,
           fetching after a COMMIT has been issued will return the error.
           3) Rebinding any placeholders in the SQL statement, then issuing
           a fetch before reexecuting the statement.
*Action:   1) Do not issue a fetch statement after the last row has been
           retrieved - there are no more rows to fetch.
           2) Do not issue a COMMIT inside a fetch loop for a cursor
           that has been opened FOR UPDATE.
           3) Reexecute the statement after rebinding, then attempt to
           fetch again.
```

If I run the script without the rollback and then issue the rollback separately everything is fine. But that will make for an annoying test unit later on.

Answer (score 1):

Found out the problem!
Turns out oracle SQL developer only returns 50 rows at a time by default. So after I start scrolling down it will go off and fetch the next 50 rows which makes for possibly invalid results seen as the select was issued before the rollback and I get an error. Fixed by going into preference->database and changing the return size which luckily for me was just inside the max amount they allow (200 results).

Comment: So you're running the insert as a statement, running the query as a statement, switching back from the grid view to the worksheet, running the  rollback as a statement, and then going back to the grid view and scrolling down? If you're writing a script, why not run it as a script rather than individual statements?

Comment: I have the insert, query and rollback statement that I run in one go from a worksheet. I don't have to do any switching. Sql developer returns the query results in a window. I thought writing a bunch of statements in a worksheet was a script.

Comment: OK, then you're selecting/highlighting the three statements and doing 'Run statement' (control-enter) of all of them together. The effect is the same - you can even see it showing the Query Results window briefly. If you 'Run Script' (F5) then the output goes into the Script Output window instead of the Query Result window (a different limit applies there, 5000 by default; set in Tools->Preferences->Database->Worksheet).and the rollback isn't issued until all the fetches have been completed, so you won't get that error. You may particularly want the grid output though.